# Hide volume HUD view in MPVolumeView

Tags: ios, swift, mpvolumeview

I use `MPVolumeView` and `UISlider` to control my device audio and below is my code:

```
extension MPVolumeView {
    var volumeSlider: UISlider {
        self.showsRouteButton = false
        self.showsVolumeSlider = true

        var slider = UISlider()
        for subview in self.subviews {
            if subview.isKind(of: UISlider.self){
                slider = subview as! UISlider
                slider.isContinuous = false
                slider.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor.outlineStrokeColor
                slider.setThumbImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "volume"), for: .normal)
                slider.maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
                (subview as! UISlider).value = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().outputVolume
                return slider
            }
        }
        return slider
    }
}


let mpVolumeView: MPVolumeView = {
    let view = MPVolumeView()
    return view
}()

override func viewDidLoad() { 
    _ = mpVolumeView.volumeSlider
    view.addSubview(mpVolumeView)
}
```

Everything works great but everytime when I open my app, the volume HUD appears and fades away after a few seconds. It won't show up again after that but I wish there would be an option to hide it all the time. I have tried to set MPVolumeView's frame to .zero but it still doesn't work. Is there a way that I can do so?

[image: sample image]

Comment: you created a weak reference where are you calling in didLoad or WillAppear ?

Comment: I didn't create a weak reference and I called it in viewDidLoad

Comment: if you calling this In viewDidLoad it Will always appear for the first time when your respective screen is loaded to memory stack , so avoid calling it unnecessarily in didLoad and just call it where you need it, I think this Line "view.addSubview(mpVolumeView)" show it , so just add it in view only when it is necessary no need to use this line in didLoad

Comment: I mean I don't need the volume HUD. I just need to show user the volume slider with other UIs in ViewDidLoad. Any suggestions on where I should call it?

Comment: Yes. I want to hide the volume UI which has a speaker image in my app and only shows the slider at the bottom of the screen for user to control volume.

Comment: where are you setting its frame to zero ?

Comment: Possible can you share sample code ?

Comment: I tried let view = MPVolumeView(frame: .zero)