# Hide volume HUD (avoid use of loaded view)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, view, volume

**This question is no duplicate to**:

- [Hide volume HUD view in MPVolumeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48071333/hide-volume-hud-view-in-mpvolumeview)
- [Hide device Volume HUD view while adjusitng volume with MPVolumeView slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444376/hide-device-volume-hud-view-while-adjusitng-volume-with-mpvolumeview-slider?rq=1)

---

> I'd like to hide the **system volume HUD**  while adjusting the volume programmately without the need of a loaded View.

[image: img]

**So this solution is not what I'd like to get (in my case this is not acceptable):**

```
let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: .zero)
view.addSubview(volumeView)
```

---

I'd like to get a working function to hide the volumeView while avoiding to add hidden Subview instead.

This is what I've got so far (however this is not working currently) :

```
func hideHUD() {
  let volumeWindow: UIWindow = UIWindow()
  let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: .zero)

  volumeView.isHidden = false
  volumeWindow.isHidden = true
  volumeWindow.addSubview(volumeView) 
}
```

**Note:** I'm pretty sure It is possible to hide the volume HUD programmately because the *VolumeBar API* ([you can find here](https://github.com/gizmosachin/VolumeBar/blob/master/Sources/VolumeBar.swift)) is able to hide the HUD and replace it with it's own style!

Comment: As I've gathered from reading around SO, the method you're trying to use only work when an AVAudioSession is active (video probably works too). So that's a necessity to make it work this way.

Comment: Added this line - but will also affect nothing of my code: `try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)`

Comment: Also add a category: `try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.ambient, mode: .default, options: [])`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you want may not be possible. The *VolumeBar* project you linked uses an invisible MPVolumeView to hide the system HUD just like others have suggested. [See here](https://github.com/gizmosachin/VolumeBar/blob/f8bd5311bc1e90a071836718bd5da220fdb54a38/Sources/Internal/VolumeBarWindow.swift#L40)

```
/// A standard iOS `MPVolumeView` that never appears but is necessary to hide the system volume HUD.
private let systemVolumeView: MPVolumeView
```

...

```
// Add a non-hidden MPVolumeView with a zero frame to prevent the system volume HUD from showing
systemVolumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: .zero)
systemVolumeView.isHidden = false
systemVolumeView.clipsToBounds = true
systemVolumeView.showsRouteButton = false
systemVolumeView.alpha = 0.0001
```

Source: https://github.com/gizmosachin/VolumeBar/blob/master/Sources/Internal/VolumeBarWindow.swift